# Correct JWT nuget package for ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

I found two nuget package for JWT;

1. System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt
2. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer

What is the correct (or good) to implement JWT authentication in ASP.NET Core Web API?

Best regards.

Comment: Did you check the descriptions? The first is only used to create or validate JWTs. The second adds authentication to the application and may already be included through the ASP.NET Core SDK. To add authentication to your Web API project you need the second one

Comment: I suspect what you really need is a tutorial on how to add JWT authentication like [Implementing JWT Authentication in ASP.NET Core 5](https://www.codemag.com/Article/2105051/Implementing-JWT-Authentication-in-ASP.NET-Core-5)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was confused for a while because of namespace of System.* and Microsoft.* (I am familiar with ASP.NET 5, not ASP.NET Core). Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer refers System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt and it is essential to ASP.NET Core JWT authentication.

Comment: So, can we end this case here?